# Closest monospace fonts to tahoma

Tags: fonts

I want to know the closest monospace font to ***tahoma***.

I've a [list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_typefaces#Monospace) of monospace fonts.

I can't use tahoma as is it not monospace.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Vera Space mono is what I use personally. It looks great like tahoma. Ubuntu mono looks great, but it's quite different, still sharp though. These are personal opinions though.